# chrome. printerProvider with Google Cloud Print

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os, google-cloud-print

The chrome.printerProvider API allows the creation of printer drivers, that are accessible for local print from the browser.

Is there a way to use this extension to create a Google Cloud Print printer, that can be accessed over the network (like you could use the Chrome browser integrated Proxy for local Windows printers)?

Does this work under Chrome OS?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Google Cloud Print](https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?hl=en). Cloud Ready printers connect directly to the web. With Classic printers, you need a computer to set up the web connection.

Furthermore, you'll have to check if your printer is in the [list of Cloud Ready printers](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/printers.html) for you to do this.

Comment: Cloud Print Ready Printers handle the communication with Google Cloud Print on their own. We want to bring legacy printers without that capability into the system, that require an intelligent device to handle the protocol. There is a functionality ich the Chrome browser that allows you to bring any Windows or Mac printer into the system. We want to do a similar thing with a printer connected to Chrome OS

Comment: It seems I've yet to see that implementation.